# Example for offline application in tabris

Tags: android, offline, tabris

has anyone created an offline application using Tabris framework? With the Tabris 1.3 release (see [link](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/03/10/tabris-1-3-is-here-open-sourcing-passe-partout/) ) this seems possible, but I do not know how to start ?

Answer (score 0):

It's in internal feature right now. We are currently stabilizing it and will create API for it. You can expect a developer preview in summer this year.